# Surface integral of second kind trivia question

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I am preparing to the calculus test and I am concerted about surface integrals of second kind.

Please tell me if $\iint_{S}P \,dy\,dz =\iint_{S}P \,dz\,dy$ or $\iint_{S}P \,dy\,dz =-\iint_{S}P \,dz\,dy$.

I am not sure if it is notation question, or mathematical one. In *all* my textbooks I see $dy\,dz$, $dz\,dx$ and $dx\,dz$.

But in my sample test I see the following: $\iint_{S}x^2 \,dy\,dx +3x \,dz\,dy$. I worry a lot about my (mis)understanding.

Thanks a lot for you answers!

Comment: Changing the order of integration will not change the value of the integral.

Comment: So, they are the same due to _mathematical_ reasons, right?

Comment: if f(x,y) is continuous or piece-wise continuous over the region of integration, you can swap the order with out fear.  If f(x,y) is running off to infinity somewhere in there, you may find that the integral still converges, but you cannot swap the order of integration.